# Determine the nonzero natural numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{a+b+c}2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the nonzero natural numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which
$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{a+b+c}2.$

I tried $\times 2$ and then it becomes $$\frac2a+\frac2b+\frac2c=a+b+c.$$

After some simplifications we got to $$\frac{2bc+2ac+2ab}{abc}=a+b+c.$$

We break the $()$ and I think the only solution is $a^2=2$, $b^2=2$, $c^2=2$ and it is impossible.

Comment: Question needs a bit of a cleanup

Comment: i know...but i dont really understand how I should do it.... sorry

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: thank you...im gonna take a glance at it

Comment: Hint: $(a+b+c)/2\geq \frac32.$

Comment: @IonelaBuciu I fixed some of the notation but some of the steps are wrong from what I can make out.

Comment: Ah, that happened in the edit. Fixed.

Comment: This is (elementary-number-theory), not (linear-algebra).

Comment: I understand your hint but i dont know where it does help me....a>1 b>1 c>1 [+]

Comment: We got a+b+c>3 and the :2

Comment: But where i should use it?

Comment: try considering the case $a,b,c \geq 2$: $1/a+1/b+1/c<3/2<3<(a+b+c)/2$ and since $1 \leq a,b,c$ at least one of them should be equal to $1$. due to the symmetry let it be $c$ and you get a reduced problem to solve: $1/a+1/b+1=(a+b+1)/2$.

Comment: Okey but how do you solve the little problem you made

Comment: Take a look at this wolfram alpha query: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2Fa%29%2B%281%2Fb%29%2B%281%2Fc%29%3D%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%2F2

Comment: $c = \frac{\sqrt{((8 a^2 b^2 + (a^2 (-b) - a b^2 + 2 a + 2 b)^2)} + a^2 (-b) - a b^2 + 2 a + 2 b)}{(2 a b)}$

Comment: Hint since both the LHS and RHS is symmetric, you can take $x\in{a,b,c}$ as a polynomial, then write out your expression in terms of the elementary symmetric of the polynomial, then check It's discriminate to see the the equation has no Integers solutions

Comment: I checked brute force for all combinations of 500 natural numbers and found no solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{a+b+c}2$$

Let us first consider the case $a\leqslant b\leqslant c$.

Suppose that $2\leqslant a$. Then, we have
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\leqslant \frac 12+\frac 12+\frac 12=\frac 32$$
and
$$\frac{a+b+c}{2}\geqslant \frac{2+2+2}{2}=3$$

Therefore, we have to have $a=1$, and

$$1+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=\frac{1+b+c}{2}$$
i.e.
$$\frac 1b+\frac 1c=\frac{b+c-1}{2}$$

Now, suppose that $2\leqslant b$. Then, we have
$$\frac 1b+\frac 1c\leqslant \frac 12+\frac 12=1$$
and
$$\frac{b+c-1}{2}\geqslant \frac{2+2-1}{2}=\frac 32$$

Therefore, we have to have $b=1$, and so
$$1+\frac 1c=\frac{1+c-1}{2}$$
which is equivalent to $c^2-2c-2=0$, and so $c=1\pm\sqrt{3}$ which are not integers.

Therefore, there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$\dfrac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}=\dfrac{a+b+c}2,$$
then
$$abc(a+b+c)=2(ab+bc+ca),\tag1$$
$$(a+b+c)^2-abc(a+b+c)=a^2+b^2+c^2\ge\dfrac13(a+b+c)^2.$$
Therefore, WLOG
$$\dfrac1{bc}+\dfrac1{ca}+\dfrac1{ab}\ge \dfrac32, \quad a\ge b\ge c,\quad a,b,c\in \mathbb N,\tag2$$
with the possible solutions
$$(a,b,c)\in\{(1,1,1), (2,1,1), (3,1,1)\},$$
which does not satisfy $(1).$

**No solutions.**

Answer (score 1):

Since, $(1,1,x), (2,2,1), (3,2,1)$ and their permutations are not a solution of the given equation, for a positive integer solution, $a,b,c$ must satisfy
$$\frac{a+b+c}{2}\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{abc}\geq\frac32\sqrt[3]8\geq3$$
where we used of [AM-GM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AM-GM_Inequality). Hence, we have
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\geq3.$$
The last inequality is true only for $(1,1,1)$ over positive integers. But, this triple is already excluded. So, the equation $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ has no positive integer solution.